# Typescript giving error on defining type defination for object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

hi guys i have an array of objects like -

```
const routes = [
  {
    path: '/',
    exact: true,
    name: 'Home',
    component: Home,
    authRequired: false
  },
  {
    path: '/seguro-vida-credito/simulacao/:journeyId?',
    exact: true,
    name: 'MortgageJourney',
    component: MortageJourney,
    authRequired: true
  }
]
```

so in my component first of all i am defining the type for my object like

```
interface RouteType {
  path: string,
  exact: boolean,
  name: string,
  component: React.Component,
  authRequired: boolean,
  title?:string,
}
```

and then i want to loop over this and render my routes

```
export default function HandleRoutes() {
  return (
    <>
      {routes.map((route: RouteType) => {
        console.log(route)
        return route.authRequired ? (
          <ProtectedRoutes
            exact
            path={route.path}
            key={index}
            component={route.component}
            name={route.name}
            title={route.title}
          />
        ) : (
          <Route
            component={route.component}
            exact={route.exact}
            key={index}
            name={route.name}
            path={route.path}
            title={route.title}
          />
        )
      })}
    </>
  )
}
```

but typescript is giving me error on map function by saying

> Argument of type '(route: RouteType, index: number) => JSX.Element' is
> not assignable to parameter of type '(value: { path: string; exact:
> boolean; name: string; component:
> LazyExoticComponent<ConnectedComponent<typeof Home,
> Omit<Pick<PropsType, "history"> & Pick<InferProps<{ history:
> Validator; }>, never> & Pick<...>, never>>>; authRequired:
> boolean; } | { ...; }, index: number, array: ({ ...; } | { ...; })[])
> => El...'.   Types of parameters 'route' and 'value' are incompatible.
> Type '{ path: string; exact: boolean; name: string; component: LazyExoticComponent<ConnectedComponent<typeof Home,
> Omit<Pick<PropsType, "history"> & Pick<InferProps<{ history:
> Validator; }>, never> & Pick<...>, never>>>; authRequired:
> boolean; } | { ...; }' is not assignable to type 'RouteType'.
> Type '{ path: string; exact: boolean; name: string; component: React.LazyExoticComponent<ConnectedComponent<typeof Home,
> Omit<Pick<PropsType, "history"> & Pick<InferProps<{ history:
> Validator; }>, never> & Pick<...>, never>>>; authRequired:
> boolean; }' is not assignable to type 'RouteType'.
> Types of property 'component' are incompatible.
> Type 'ExoticComponent<Omit<Pick<PropsType, "history"> & Pick<InferProps<{ history: Validator; }>, never> &
> Pick<PropsType, never>, never>> & { ...; }' is missing the following
> properties from type 'Component<{}, {}, any>': context, setState,
> forceUpdate, render, and 3 more.

May i know what it is exactly trying to say ? i have already defined type for my routes
Thanks

Comment: This is what you are looking for - https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-goldberg-88ym9?file=/src/App.tsx

Answer (score 0):

You can initialize the type for array only , and use ComponentType(accepts react class and function compoennt) instead of Component

```
interface RouteType {
  path: string;
  exact: boolean;
  name: string;
  component: ComponentType;
  authRequired: boolean;
  title?: string;
}

const Test: FC = () => {
  return <div>Test</div>;
};

const routes:Array<RouteType> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    exact: true,
    name: "Home",
    component: Home,
    authRequired: false
  },
  {
    path: "/seguro-vida-credito/simulacao/:journeyId?",
    exact: true,
    name: "MortgageJourney",
    component: Home,
    authRequired: true
  }
];
```